# How to show the image properly?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using this to show an image background:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/picture_happy"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
```

The image is distorted. Is there a way to show the pixels 1:1? Just crop off from the display what flows over?

I am am not worried about the what is cropped off.

Thanks!
Eric

**Upate to add image**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Change the scaleType to `centerCrop`:

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

For more information on scale types refer to this image:

[image]

Top row (from left to right):

center, centerCrop, centerInside. Bottom row (l-r): fitCenter, fitStart, fitEnd, fitXY.

Comment: Thanks Ahmad, but this does not seem to do it. Doesn't seem to actually do anything when I add `android:scaleType="centerInside"` to my RelativeLayout.

Comment: Is your RelativeLayout your parent layout or is it a child layout?

Comment: It is the top most element.

Comment: Ah ok. I think I misunderstood what you wanted your image to look like. Should it be stretched  throughout the whole screen, not crop off or should it keep its aspect ratio and stretch itself.(I suggested you the second, but after rereading your question I think you might want it the third way...)

Comment: Regardless of the option I choose, there is no change. As you can see from the example above, I already tried that. I am thinking android:scaleType is not allowed in the RelativeLayout element.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your screen?

Comment: The image I just added is obviously a placeholder until I get the photo I want but it should work nevertheless.

Comment: If `centerCrop` is not working then I can't tell why. What happens when you remove the scaleType completely?

Comment: When I remove it, it looks exactly the same as when it is there. That is why I think that it might not be supported. But, there has to be a way to do it.